# Opening window, no matter which button I press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a game with tkinter. Now I wanted to make a window, that opens, when I'm pressing 6. But the problem is, it opens every time I press a button (no matter what button). But I just want it to open, when you press 6. So it is even opening, when I press space, or m, n ...

```py
self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.root.title("Win Number Changer")

        def key_6():
            global board, playing, statusMessage
            if event.keysym == "6":
                self.root.mainloop()
            else:
                pass
```

I want the window to open, when I'm pressing 6. But not, if I'm pressing any other button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It makes it much easier for us to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the `root` window by pressing key `6`, you can do the following:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import keyboard

keyboard.wait(hotkey='6')
root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Win Number Changer')
root.mainloop()
```

Or if you want to spawn additional `TopLevel` windows on the press of the button, do the following:

```
import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Win Number Changer')

def key_6(event):
    if event.keysym == '6':
        Tk.Toplevel(root) #spawns new window
        root.withdraw() #hides the root window

root.bind('<Key>', key_6)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried example nr. 2 and it is not working, sadly. And idea why?

Comment: It works for me. I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Comment: Plus questions like 'any idea why' is difficult to answer if I do not see the Traceback error